# nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Caches have distinct sets of data nodes

Tags: ignite

our ignite cluster have 5 nodes, we have a problem whenever there's a node restarted (when the Node restarted, rebalance process will be trigged in cluster), when we execute query by join two tables (cache), it throw exception like below

nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Caches have distinct sets of data nodes

when the rebalance process completed, the issue almost resolved,
anyone has the same issue? how to avoid or fix it

Comment: pls help or sharing any your experience about this issue